# There seems to be a problem with the Footer and text [Screenshots attached]

Tags: header-footer, margins, text

[image: Instance 1]
[image: Instance 2]
[image: Instance 3]

It's been quite sometime, and i have noticed that on some pages, in my report that actually overlap with the footer.
The footer is generated perfectly but the text seems not disciplined in some pages.
Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT**: Has little or nothing to do with pagination, the following screenshot was taken when i moved all the pagination specifications to before `\begin{document}`
[image: when pagination moved before \begin{document}]

code: (please ignore the comments)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}%Memoir is more versatile than other document classes like article, report, book etc,
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}%to handle image, like scaling
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=1in]{geometry}%used for modifying page layout
\usepackage{hyperref}%for referencing contents,figure,table...
\usepackage{listings}%for including source code
\usepackage{pdfpages}%to attach pdf files
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{
    \thispagestyle{chapter}}{
    \thispagestyle{myheadings}
}{}{}
\pagenumbering{roman}


%document starts here
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\newlength{\toptafiddle} 
\newlength{\bottafiddle}
\include{title}%include titlepage,i.e, title.tex file
%Page layout according to VTU specification
%Right=1.25in,left=1in, Top & Bottom 0.75in in each
%Left – 1.25″, Right – 1″, Top and Bottom – 0.75″
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}%left side margin{1in by default+0.25in}

%header specification
\setlength{\headheight}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{6pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.25in}

%footer specification
\setlength{\footskip}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\onelineskip}

%A4 paper height = 11.69in
%thus 11.69in-9.67in-1in(top+header) is approx 0.75in left for bottom
\setlength{\textheight}{9.67in}

\brokenpenalty=10000% Disallow page breaks at hyphens

\OnehalfSpacing

\include{certificate}
\include{declaration}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{abstract}
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{acknowledge}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}%sections numbering upto 2 level.i.e,chapter,section,subsection & any later sections will not be numbered
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\begin{KeepFromToc}
\tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}
\pagebreak
\listoffigures
\pagebreak
%\listoftables 
%\pagebreak
%creating custom header & footer. Look into memoir manual for details
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\makeheadrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\makefootrule{myheadings}{\textwidth}{0.4pt}{\footruleskip}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\small{Face Based Biometric Automated Attendance System}}{}{\small{Chapter \thechapter}}
\makeoddfoot{myheadings}{\small{Dept. of CSE, P.A.C.E}}{}{\small{\thepage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\justifying
\include{introduction}
\include{literaturesurvey}
\include{softwarerequirementanalysis}
\include{systemanalysis}
\include{algorithms}
\include{systemsdesign}
\include{systemimplementation}
\include{softwaretesting}
\include{results}
\include{conclusion}
\include{reference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example please?

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson Minimal example of? in the screenshots pages (2,8,12) have this issue, where as pg 11 is perfect

Comment: the code you used to produce the text and footer.

Comment: to be more explicit, perhaps the preamble code and the first two pages plus the \end{document} would be enough :-)?

Comment: Nice. Another guessing game. A little margin and/or little foot skip ? Try some like `\usepackage[bmargin=5cm,footskip=2cm,showframe]{geometry}`  and then change this setting as you need.

Comment: Are you using `fancyhdr`?

Comment: @egreg NO i am not using fancyhdr

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16316181/

Comment: @user270840 Changing the pagination parameters *after* `\begin{document}` is the cause of your troubles.

Comment: but i need that pagination, else it will violate my university norms for a report.

Comment: but then, as already has been suggested you could set your page size relatively flexibly using `\usepackage[]{geometry}` and control the **pagination** (e.g. how the text is broken up onto separate pages) like @Fran suggests or wait until your document is written and add either `\pagebreak[number]` or `\nopagebreak[number]` as required to pretty it up.

Comment: ok, i'll search for solution related to pagination

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson I've tried the pagination with `\frontmatter` `\mainmatter` still not working, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @user270840 but `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` control **numbering formats**. Pagination is something quite different.

Comment: ok, i did a bit of research in pagination, so i did move the pagination details before \begin document, but i'm still getting the same issue (on very few pages now)

Comment: what have you set the `\footskip` to?

Comment: the foot skip was the problem, i have resolved it by changing the footskip value

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from @ulrike-fischer on chat.stackexchange.com
The problem with the document is that footskip is too small. 
Usage of `\setlength{\footskip}{2\onelineskip}` Resolves the issue!

Comment: perhaps @UlrikeFischer should post this answer?